# Copy value from one spreadtab to another

Tags: calculations, spreadtab

I have two tables. The first only does calculations with spreadtab and has some final result that I tag (with spreadtab's ommand `tab`). Later, I want to reuse the value in another spreadtab, but I do not know how to do this. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{spreadtab}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\section{Try 1 - Using package FP}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabu} to \textwidth {ll}}
@ A         & 1234 tag(personalkostenI)
\end{spreadtab}
\FPset\personalkosten{\STtag{personalkostenI}}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}}
@ B         & \FPprint\personalkostenI 
\end{spreadtab}



\section{Try 2  - using spreadtab}

\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell\personalkostenII{b1}]{{tabu} to \textwidth {ll}}
@ A         & 1234
\end{spreadtab}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}}
@ B         & \personalkostenII
\end{spreadtab}



\section{Try 3 - Only using tag}

\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell\personalkostenII{b1}]{{tabu} to \textwidth {ll}}
@ A         & 1234 tag(personalkostenIII)
\end{spreadtab}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}}
@ B         & \STtag{personalkostenIII}
\end{spreadtab}



\end{document}
```

For the third variant I get the error messages

[image]

Comment: the third variant should work fine. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: When I comment the first and second try I get the displayed error message.

Comment: Works ok for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: No, I am on Kubuntu 14.4. So my packages are kind of old, because the newest are not in the repo.

Comment: Can't you install a vanilla texlive 2018?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't know how. I tried to look into the topic, but it always seemed like quite a chore.